# Button present and Displayed clicked Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

How to check when scrolling down stopped working?

The code works, it clicks the button but after a while the button that is still displayed and present doesn't load any new data on the page. Even without the code, if you press the button e.g. 25 times after the 25th time you press manually the button but nothing changes, no new items being shown on the page.

pseudo code (this way is just to demonstrate the idea, nothing else)

```
from selenium import webdriver

count =0 
displayed = driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').is_displayed()
enabled = driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').is_enabled()

if displayed and enabled:
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').click

if count => 26:
   break 

count +=1
```

is there any way to detect the effect of a button press or not in selenium?

Or is there a way to check the page difference on every button press?
e.g. is it the same as before clicked on the button or different once button pressed(more elements added to the page?)

Because it can be always detectable and clickable but after a while there is no effect of pressing it, thus therefore the question.

Comment: Do you just want to come out of loop after clicking for 25th time ?

Comment: instead of manually settling for some number of clicks to break the code, is there any function that detects same elements remaining on the page even after button click? if so that's when the code should brake instead of me saying some static number, that might change.

Comment: @cruisepandey is the problem clear or should I rephrase it?

Comment: I think I got it, but looks bit complex from use case perspective ? When the data did not get displayed after clicking on the button, do you see white screen or blank screen ? Can you locate that element "the blank one " ? If yes then we can automate this process

Comment: it's a webpage crawler, single page that should be scrolling all upon till it doesn't. There is always the previous information being displayed but after a while it doesn't add up any new information,remains the same. Maybe with some timer-counter to solve it?

Comment: when you click on next button, some events must have been fired right ? we need to determine that first

Comment: Nothing changes that's the thing everything remains. at least not visible to my eyes. Maybe inside of the whole page something happens but it doesn't scroll anymore.

Comment: Can you share URL, I can have a look